# PWA install usually hangs on Android

Tags: android, angular, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA that installs no problem on a desktop every single time so I know it's configured properly.  But for some reason, on several different Android devices when I try to install the PWA it says installing but nothing happens.  There is no icon ever created on the home screen or within apps.  Also, it will say `Adding <AppName>...` in my notifications and it will sit there for like 5 minutes or even much longer.  When it finally goes away there is still no indication that it is installed anywhere.

Also strange is that Sometimes after a period of time all of the installs that I've been trying to install will suddenly show up with their own independent icons, so I'll have like 5 icons for the same PWA app in my apps list.  I've had a couple times where it installs with no issue, but most often I have to keep playing around until it finally installs.

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?

Here is the only thing I could find remotely related to my app or any sort of install in my logcat.  As a side note: there are no messages of any kind when looking at the console for the webpage while remote debugging.

```
08-16 11:54:31.108  4828  4828 D Notification.Badge: [invalid] onNotificationPosted : StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.android.chrome user=UserHandle{0} id=-1 tag=webapk_install_notification_tag_prefix.https://myapp.mycomp.com/myappname/manifest.webmanifest key=0|com.android.chrome|-1|webapk_install_notification_tag_prefix.https://myapp.mycomp.com/myappname/manifest.webmanifest|10084: Notification(channel=browser pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x10 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE semFlags=0x0 semPriority=0 semMissedCount=0))
08-16 11:54:32.024  8839  9252 W DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
08-16 11:54:32.626  8839  9252 I Finsky  : [690] lhr.a(3): WebAPK service install success
08-16 11:54:32.639  8839  8839 I Finsky  : [2] lwy.b(3): Scheduling install request package_name=org.chromium.webapk.a4c2bd9ecd2308c4e, version=1, priority=2, reason=webapk_install, account_name=[AEbby1tRgdo4u6hvkd7E6mNvRlU], type=2, constraints=((NETWORK=ANY, PROVISIONING_STATE=PROVISIONED),)
08-16 11:54:32.893  8839  9000 I Finsky  : [683] lwy.b(37): No matching installs to run for jobs: []
3  4828  4828 D Notification.Badge: [invalid] onNotificationRemoved : StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.android.chrome user=UserHandle{0} id=-1 tag=webapk_install_notification_tag_prefix.https://myapp.mycomp.com/myappname/manifest.webmanifest key=0|com.android.chrome|-1|webapk_install_notification_tag_prefix.https://myapp.mycomp.com/myappname/manifest.webmanifest|10084: Notification(channel=browser pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x10 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE semFlags=0x0 semPriority=0 semMissedCount=0))
08-16 12:02:58.394  4828  4828 D Notification.Badge: [invalid] onNotificationPosted : StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.android.chrome user=UserHandle{0} id=-1 tag=webapk_install_notification_tag_prefix.https://myapp.mycomp.com/myappname/manifest.webmanifest key=0|com.android.chrome|-1|webapk_install_notification_tag_prefix.https://myapp.mycomp.com/myappname/manifest.webmanifest|10084: Notification(channel=browser pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x10 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE semFlags=0x0 semPriority=0 semMissedCount=0))
08-16 12:02:59.231  8839  8858 I Finsky  : [628] lgv.a(2): installPackage: com.android.chrome (org.chromium.webapk.afe6dd94a4495fbd3)
08-16 12:02:59.682  8839  8858 I Finsky  : [628] lhr.a(3): WebAPK service install success
08-16 12:02:59.688  8839  8839 I Finsky  : [2] lwy.b(3): Scheduling install request package_name=org.chromium.webapk.afe6dd94a4495fbd3, version=1, priority=2, reason=webapk_install, account_name=[AEbby1tRgdo4u6hvkd7E6mNvRlU], type=2, constraints=((NETWORK=ANY, PROVISIONING_STATE=PROVISIONED),)
08-16 12:02:59.759  8839  9000 I Finsky  : [683] lwy.b(37): No matching installs to run for jobs: []
```

Comment: Are you seeing anything in either [Chrome Remote Debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) or [adb logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat) when attempting an install?

Comment: @MorrisonChang I'll check that

Comment: Note that Chrome Remote Debugging I think uses it own adb server so don't try to use both Chrome debugging and `adb` at the same time.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I updated my question with more info

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue when trying to install a PWA on Android, and realized that I had disabled the `Add app icons to Home screen` setting. Once I re-enabled that option via `Long press on Home screen > Home settings`, the PWA installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the home screen setting for "Add new apps to Home Screen". Ensure that the setting is enabled and try to install the PWA again. Here is my setting on my Samsung phone
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eod5t.jpg)